# Unable to create an app with HealthKit capability enabled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, provisioning-profile, healthkit

I am trying to create an iOS app on XCode 10 and I am trying to enable the HealthKit capability, but I am getting some errors. I have a red exclamation mark on the "Capabilities" screen where it says "Add the healthkit feature to your App ID". And on the "General" tab, I get an error "Provisioning profile ... doesn't include the com.apple.developer.healthkit.access entitlement." Please refer to the attached screenshots.

This is a freshly created iOS app, so there are no codes yet on this one. Also please do note that my developer account is a free one. I'm wondering if I need a paid developer account to integrate HealthKit to an app? I remembered that I was able to do use HealthKit before with the same account.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE: I discovered that when creating a new app and enabling HealthKit using XCode 9 didn't have this problem. When I opened this app on XCode 10 beta 3, it seems to work, but then if I enable/disable the HealthKit from XCode 10, the problem persists again. Already reported as a Bug to Apple.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Enable health kit from Xcode >> project navigator >> capabilities tab >> health kit

Comment: Yes, I did that, hence the screenshot above. :-)

Comment: Do you enable Automatically manage signing from General tab?

Comment: Yes I did enable signing automatically

Comment: Please try to remove .entitlements file from your project, then enable health kit for this app from apple developer portal, then try again from Xcode

Comment: I don't have access to that I'm afraid as I have a free developer account. The developer portal only shows me 'downloads' and the link to the forum.

Comment: You will need a paid membership to activate this entitlement

Comment: It seems like you have to enable on developer portal for app identifier this app service as well. And then update your provisioning profile too.
DeveloperPortal->Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles->AppID's->Choose your App ID -> Edit-> Enable HealthKit->Save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem I was having might be due to a bug in XCode 10 beta 3. So I reported it already, and I have found a workaround. I just created the new project in a stable version of XCode 9, then enabled HealthKit from there. Then I opened the project in XCode 10, and continued working from there.

UPDATE: Bug has been fixed on XCode 10 Beta 6